# Springboot - validating enum

Tags: spring-boot, validation, jackson

I have an enum that I am validating like this:

```
@EnumValueValidator(enumClass = MyEnum.class)
String value
```

It's a string field, but it is validated against a list of enums.  However, once the validation is completed, and I know the field is valid, I want the getter to return the enum.
So I added a getter like this

```
public MyEnum getValue()
  return MyEnum.valueOf(value)
```

The problem is if the value is not one of the valid enum types, the validation doesn't issue the proper error message, because it gets an exception calling the getter on the invalid type.  I don't want the validation to use the getter.  It should use the field directly.  The getter() should only be used by explicit calls in the business logic.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you actually want to validate that a String matches a valid value for your `MyEnum` instead of using `MyEnum`directly as the type of your `value` attribute and let it be automatically validated?

Comment: Because if the String can't be converted to an enum, you get a nasty exception, instead of a nice error to the user telling him that the string 'foo' is not a valid value for the enum

Comment: The thing is that by doing so, if you have API documentation (OpenAPI for example), you do not provide the necessary information to the callers of your API about which values are valid for that Enum and by doing so they are on their own on guessing which are the valid ones. Additionally, `@EnumValueValidator` seems to be a custom validator and without its implementation I can't really help you further.

Comment: Yes, it's a custom validator because there isn't a built-in one.   Lots of examples online.  Making in an Enum type does not do any validation.  If the user enters an incorrect value, an exception is thrown.  How do you suggest actually validating an enum, given that the user might pass in any arbitrary string, including null?  The Swagger documentation defines what the valid fields are, but that doesn't mean the user will always follow it.

Comment: Yes, an exception is thrown and you can use such an exception to build your message to the caller (with a Global Exception Handler) based on its default message. And yes, you are right, the user is not forced to always use a valid value, but at least the user is aware of the valid values, with a `String` attribute the user can only guess. In the end, this is an API design decision and I was just suggesting other approaches. Is your implementation similar to the one in https://funofprograming.wordpress.com/2016/09/29/java-enum-validator/ ?

Comment: Yes, that's similar to the implementation I'm using.  The problem I'm having with your approach is that there is no actual Validation being done.  And again, even with a String value, the user can still be told what the valid values are.  User doesn't care if it's an enum or just a list of valid strings.

Comment: If that is the case it seems to me that the value is not being validated at all, because I can't find any explicit call to `getValue()`. But I might be missing something here.

Comment: It's not explicit. Spring uses it with reflection

Comment: But why would Spring be doing that since you have String as the attribute type? And looking into https://funofprograming.wordpress.com/2016/09/29/java-enum-validator/ I also can't find a reason. Either you provide your full implementation or it will be hard to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure you fully understand how Springboot does validation and how it uses reflection to load beans

Comment: With so little code context in your question for sure I don't understand it.